# Unable to loop through API response / access loop variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter

I'm trying to build a simple Twitter feed app, but I'm having difficulty implementing a refresh function.

```
    $scope.refreshTimeline = function() {
  for (x = 0; x < $scope.tweetsarray.length; x++){ // loop through the twitter feeds
    twitterService.getLatestTweets($scope.tweetsarray[x].name).then(function(data) {
      $scope.tweetsarray[x].tweets = data; //update each
    });
  }
}
```

and the getlatesttweets function

```
getLatestTweets: function (name) {
        //create a deferred object using Angular's $q service
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var promise = authorizationResult.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q='+name+'&count=8').done(function(data) {
            //when the data is retrieved resolved the deferred object
            deferred.resolve(data)
        });
        //return the promise of the deferred object
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

So here are the issues I'm having

1) The value of x (global variable, unused anywhere else) in the .then(function(data) seems to be different from anywhere else in the loop and it doesn't seem to increment. I've tried using $scope.x or making it a function variable in the loop. The refresh works if I hardcode it to only refresh [0] in the tweetsarray, but[x] returns a separate value.

2) I'm guessing there is some kind of issue with trying to loop through a function with deferred promises. Is there a way I can make sure on each pass through the loop that the promise is returned before continuing?

Thanks I appreciate your help!

-Dave

Comment: loop runs synchronously and your ajax call inside the loop is async..., Just do.. `function setTweets(x){//youcode...}` and call `for (x = 0; x < $scope.tweetsarray.length; x++){ setTweets(x); }` with this we are creating a local copy of `x` for each ajax calls and its callback as opposed to the shared `x` variable in your case (which would have run out before your callback runs)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the closure behavior of javascript, it will take the latest x value at the time of callback from service. So try in this way.

```
 $scope.refreshTimeline = function() {
  for (var x = 0; x < $scope.tweetsarray.length; x++){ 
    storeTweets(x);       
  }
 }

 function storeTweets(x){
    twitterService.getLatestTweets($scope.tweetsarray[x].name).then(function(data) {
      $scope.tweetsarray[x].tweets = data; //update each
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
 $scope.refreshTimeline = function() {
   for (x = 0; x < $scope.tweetsarray.length; x++){ // loop through the twitter feeds
      var data;
      data.tweet = $scope.tweetsarray[x];
      twitterService.getLatestTweets($scope.tweetsarray[x].name).then(function(data) {
      $scope.tweetsarray[$scope.tweetsarray.indexof(data.tweet)].tweets = data; //update each
    });
   }
 }
```

it means, pass the array element to the async task and it comes back in the response and then use it to find the array index and update the element